# How to write repeat command in Terminal

Tags: execute-command

In my path, I have totally 120 cases, each case has two files, the path looks like this:

```
00001_FA.nii.gz 
00001_FA_grot.nii.gz
00002_FA.nii.gz  
00002_FA_grot.nii.gz
.. ..
00120_FA.nii.gz  
00120_FA_grot.nii.gz
```

I want to do `fslstats 00001_FA_nii.gz -k 00001_FA_grot.nii.gz -m` then repeat the process till the 00120 case.

How to write the command?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a loop function (`for`, for instance, is pretty helpful). Also, you need to convert 1, 2, 3 .. 119, 120 to a 5-digits format. You can do that thanks to `printf`.

And there is your script :

```bsh
for i in {1..120} ; do
  j=$(printf %05d $i)
  fslstats ${j}_FA_nii.gz -k ${j}_FA_grot.nii.gz -m
done
```

---

As @steeldriver noted in the comments, `bash` can now understand leading 0 in braces, so you can substitute

```
for i in {1..120} ; do
  j=$(printf %05d $i)
```

with
`for j in {00001..00120} ; do`

Comment: Thanks. I got it.

Comment: Note that (since bash v4.0 iirc) you can zero-pad brace expansions directly ex. `for j in {00001..00120}; do`

Comment: Thanks @steeldriver , I didn't know ! I add that to my answer and my own culture :)